# How to change Android PopupMenu width

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat, popupmenu

I am having trouble changing the width of the Appcompat PopupMenu because the menu item uses this layout abc_popup_menu_item_layout.xml in [MenuPopupHelper.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/bbbb8f39d1b1d1b317c5f9237f20fe6b1d9eb17f/appcompat/eclair/android/support/appcompat/view/menu/MenuPopupHelper.java#50), which set menu item minWidth to 196dip.

```
<android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ListMenuItemView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
        android:minWidth="196dip"
        android:paddingRight="16dip">
```

I tried to override minWidth as well as dropDownWidth in the following properties in my style.xml. I also tried to override minWidth in android:dropDownItemStyle, but it did not help. I start to wonder if it is possible to override this hard coded attribute of ListMenuItemView. Has anyone succeeded in modifying a PopupMenu width?

```
<style name="OrderDetailsActivity" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/OrderDetailsPopupMenuTextAppearanceLarge</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">@style/OrderDetailsPopupMenuTextAppearanceSmall</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/OrderDetailsListDropDownStyle</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/OrderDetailsListDropDownStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="OrderDetailsPopupMenuTextAppearanceLarge" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Widget.PopupMenu.Large">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-medium</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/font_size_medium</item>
</style>

<style name="OrderDetailsPopupMenuTextAppearanceSmall" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Widget.PopupMenu.Small">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-medium</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/font_size_medium</item>
</style>

<style name="OrderDetailsListDropDownStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:divider">@drawable/list_divider</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can prepare your custom popup menu item layout file and update this static field using reflection in onCreate() method of Your Application class:

```
private void updatePopUpMenuItemLayout() {
    try {
        Field field = MenuPopupHelper.class.getDeclaredField("ITEM_LAYOUT");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(null, R.layout.custom_popup_menu_item_layout);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("TAG", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: What is inside `custom_popup_menu_item_layout` ?

Comment: It is file with your custom popup item layout.